# PyMySQL is getting slower each consult at database

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I don't know what I'm doing wrong to connect with MySQL database...

```
class DaoImportantInfo:

    def __init__(self, db=None):
        self.db = db
        self.config = ConfigConnection()
        self.tabelas = TabelasConfig()

    def getAll(self):
        self.db.connect()
        cursor = self.db.cursor()

        strComando = f"""SELECT tetosPrevId, dataValidade, valor FROM {self.tabelas.tblTetosPrev} ORDER BY dataValidade DESC"""

        try:
            cursor.execute(strComando)
            logPrioridade(f'SELECT<getAllTetos>____________{self.tabelas.tblTetosPrev};', TipoEdicao.select, Prioridade.saidaComun)
            return cursor.fetchall()
        except:
            raise Warning(f'Erro SQL - getAllTetos({self.config.banco}) <INSERT {self.tabelas.tblTetosPrev}>')
        finally:
            self.disconectBD(cursor)


    def disconectBD(self, cursor):
        cursor.close()
        self.db.close()
```

I have a **DaoImportantInfo** class, who has the connection and some configuration properties, a method **getAll** who returns all info in *tblTetosPrev* table and **disconnectBD** that shold turn off the connection.

The weird situation is that every time I call **getAll** it takes more time to fetch all the data. The first time it takes less than one second, then, in second time, it takes 2 seconds, then 19 seconds...

I read that is important to close the connection after execute a script, so I don't know what is the problem. Can anybody help me?

I'm using Python 3.8 and Linux PopOs.

Comment: Connect _once_; do your whole program using that connection; disconnect _once_.